# Display the N of every variable category when running a logit regression

Tags: stata, logistic-regression

I want the N for every category under the variable when I run the following regression:

`logit RIC i.BMF2  Kerosene Male  ib1.agegroup3 ib5.Education2 ib3.Occupation2 i.Household_monthly Smoker, or`

so that I can have an idea if there were only a couple people in each category, or many. I understand that I could do `tab RIC variable, by(Sex)` or something along those lines for each variable, but that wouldn't ensure that is the actual number of people the regression is using (as it only takes into account people that have a response for all of the variables in the regression, correct?)

Answer (score 1):

To limit tabulate (or any command that takes an `if` option) to the estimation subsample, try this:

```
sysuse auto
logit foreign price i.rep78
tab rep78 foreign if e(sample)==1
```

The "`==1`" part is optional.